# Swift : textFieldShouldBeginEditing function fix

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The code below removes the last character in inputField and it works very well when I have the default value. But if the textField is empty there is an error because there is no last character to remove.

How to check with `if else`?

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text?.removeLast()
    percentageField.text = textField.text
    return formViewController()?.textInputShouldBeginEditing(textField, cell: self) ?? true
}
```

Comment: thanks @IvanKaloyanov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeLast` must be used on a non-empty string so make sure it's not empty:

```
if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty {
    textField.text?.removeLast()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the next way:

```
 if (!textField?.text?.isEmpty) {
   textField.text?.removeLast()
}
```

So you only removeLast if textField is empty

Comment: `textField` isn't optional.

Comment: You should fix your answer, it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can check is there any value in the textbox before performe `textField.text?.removeLast()`.

You can change your code to

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (!textField.text == "") {
        textField.text?.removeLast()
         percentageField.text = textField.text
    }
    return formViewController()?.textInputShouldBeginEditing(textField, cell: self) ?? true
}
```

Comment: There is no `isEmpty` on `UITextField`.

Comment: You can use `textField1.text == "" `

Comment: @SIDHARTHPU You should fix your answer, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
if !(textField.text!.isEmpty) {
    textField.text?.removeLast()
}
```

Refer apple doc for more details :

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1539462-isempty